# Not able to run FastAPI server, ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes

Tags: python, python-3.x, webserver, fastapi

Learning FastAPI, however, an error occurs whenever I'm trying to run it.

Error:

```
PS C:\Users\obunga\OneDrive\Desktop\py\fastfast> uvicorn main:app --reload
INFO:     Will watch for changes in these directories: ['C:\\Users\\obunga\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\py\\fastfast']
INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://127.0.0.1:8000 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
INFO:     Started reloader process [5464] using WatchFiles
Process SpawnProcess-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\obunga\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 314, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\obunga\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 108, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\obunga\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\uvicorn\_subprocess.py", line 76, in subprocess_started
    target(sockets=sockets)
  File "C:\Users\obunga\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\uvicorn\server.py", line 60, in run
    return asyncio.run(self.serve(sockets=sockets))
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\obunga\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 190, in run
    return runner.run(main)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\obunga\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 118, in run
    return self._loop.run_until_complete(task)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\obunga\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 653, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\obunga\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\uvicorn\server.py", line 67, in serve
    config.load()
  File "C:\Users\obunga\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\uvicorn\config.py", line 477, in load
    self.loaded_app = import_from_string(self.app)
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\obunga\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\uvicorn\importer.py", line 21, in import_from_string
    module = importlib.import_module(module_str)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\obunga\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1206, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1178, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1149, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 936, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1074, in get_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1004, in source_to_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes
```

I've tried **re-installing Python, FastAPI and Uvicorn**, but the error remains. My python version: 3.11.2

The code is pretty basic one: main.py -

```
from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()


@app.get("/")
def index():
    return {"lyrics": "heyyyyyyyyy"}
```

http://127.0.0.1:8000 is unreachable.

What is the issue and how to fix it?

Comment: From the error message I'm guessing that you have a 0-byte somewhere in your file, and this causes the parser to error out; the import backtrace seems to indicate that his happens when uvicorn tries to import the module to run your code. Open up the file in an editor that can show null bytes if you regular editor doesn't show those bytes (notepad++ can do that for you, and should highlight it with a special character).

Comment: @MatsLindh Tried opening the file:Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\importlib\__init__.py

It seems fine, no null bytes :(

Comment: That's not _your file_. The problem is in the file you've added the code to (or `__init__.py` or other files in your module that gets loaded automagically).

Comment: formatted main.py to utf-8, it works now. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After surfing the web for the solution for hours, one/both of these solutions worked. I found that this issue occurs when doing Django or PHP stuff too.

1. Formatting the main.py file to UTF-8
2. Formatting the files under `C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\importlib` to UTF-8.

You can format the files to UTF-8 using `VSCODE (bottom right corner->save as encoding)` or `Notepad++(encoding->convert to UTF-8)`